# Trying to get profile image from Twitter, what is wrong with this code?

Tags: php, twitter

I wrote this code, it runs but doesnt return the profile picture for me. I double checked the url for getting the pic too. Where exactly did I go wrong? 
I also want the picture that is returned to be of the size 150x150px. How do I get a custom size to be displayed. Thanks!

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/screen_name=');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $handle = $_POST['handle'];
  $size = 'bigger';
  if (isset($handle) && isset($size)) {
$twitterURL = BASE_URL . $handle . '&size=' . $size;
 }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="it-IT">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Get TwitterPic</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Get image from twitter</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="handle">Twitter Handle</label>
        <input type="text" id="twitter" name="handle" placeholder="Twitter Handle"></p>



    <p><input type="submit" value="Get Twitter Pic"></p>
    </form>
  <?php if (isset($size) && isset($twitterURL)): ?>
<img src="<?= $twitterURL ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see you setting `$gravatarURL` anywhere, and your PHP code explicitly checks `isset($gravatarURL)` before displaying the twitter URL, for some reason.

Comment: After the edit: are you sure $twitterURL is set properly? If you access it directly from your browser's address bar, is the image shown? Inspecting the code, do you see it's set properly in your <img>'s `src` property?

Comment: Yeah, accessing the url from the browser works.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Twitter's [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name) for this method:

> This method must not be used as the image source URL presented to users of your application.

This method doesn't return the image data, but rather an HTTP 302 Redirect header, redirecting an HTTP request to a new source. This won't work, and isn't supposed to work.

Also, note that you're using v1 of the Twitter API, which is deprecated and might stop working at any moment. Check out the [users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) method of the API v1.1.

Comment: Ahan...How do I rewrite my code so that the image gets displayed? Does this return only JSON?

Comment: You'll have to use curl to get the users/show data and json_decode to parse the string into an object, then you can extract the image uri and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First i was curious, because it's supposed to work. Then i've discovered multiple issues in your code.

you gotta use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/:screen_name

And this code had to be changed, you had wrong variable name:

```
<?php if (isset($size) && isset($twitterURL)): ?>
<img src="<?= $twitterURL ?>">
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Working with error_level = ALL during the development would help a lot, if you can't use modern IDE which prevent this from happening.

Comment: I corrected the code but the problem still exists. I can access the url from the browser so the url is correct.

Comment: it might be because API doesn't show image right away but redirects you to image instead. In case this is a problem you might want to request the API with curl, get the final URL and show it in your <img> tag. But code i've sent you works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Works for me too! Thanks! Figured out my mistake. But how do i change the size of the image?